# Use the same data object across multiple templates in Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to use the same data object across multiple templates in different contexts, how can I reuse it. By any chance, handlebars partials would be helpful in this situation.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
var source   = $("#homePage-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var dataPanel = {activites:[
  {activity: "Events" , activityRedirect:"#", icon:"fa fa-camera-retro" , imageUrl:"xyz"},
  {activity: "Ciriculars" , activityRedirect:"#", icon:"fa fa-paper-plane", imageUrl:"xyz"}
]};
$("#homePage-placeholder").html(template(dataPanel));
$("#another-placeholder").html(template(dataPanel));
});
```

And here is my template:

```
<script id="homePage-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                <ul>
                    {{#activites}}
                    <li><i class="{{icon}}" aria-hidden="true"></i><a href="{{activityRedirect}}">{{activity}}</a></li>
                    {{/activites}}
                </ul>

                </script>
```

Another Template

```
<script id="another-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#activites}}
  <div>
    <img src="{{imageUrl}}"/>
    <span>{{activity}}</span>
  </div>
  {{/activites}}
</script>
```

Now how can I reuse this data into "another-template", because I want an image and text in that but it renders like "homePage-template" only in form of a list, if anyone has an idea over this!

Comment: You would use it in another template in the same way you used it in the first.

Comment: can you share any example of such scenerio @76484

Comment: You are the one who wishes to reuse the object, so presumably you already have a scenario. If you post the code you've tried, then I can try to help you.

Comment: @76484, could you have a look now

Comment: Your `another-template` does not make any sense. It expects an object with two properties: `imageUrl` and `activites`, but your data object has `activites` as an array and each object in that array has an `imageUrl`.

Comment: @user2182349 if you can look into this as well ! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have a second template you must fetch its HTML source from the DOM and compile it into a template method just as you are doing for the Home Page Template.

```
var homepage_template_source = $('#homePage-template').html();
var another_template_source = $('#another-template').html();

var homepage_template = Handlebars.compile(homepage_template_source);
var another_template = Handlebars.compile(another_template_source);
```

You must call the template method for the specific template you wish to render:

```
$("#homePage-placeholder").html(homepage_template(dataPanel));
$("#another-placeholder").html(another_template(dataPanel));
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/75p16aww/) for an example.

Comment: thanks a lot! got the error, this fiddle code snippet was really helpful.